# How to handle errors if an mp3 file is corrupted while scanning through nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created a function to fetch mp3 files that are inside user's storage drives that takes an array of directories that needed to be searched. After receiving full list of music files in an array, I used that as an argument in another function that fetches it's metadata (using music metadata). So far my code is working perfectly when there are no files it returns empty array otherwise and array of objects containing their metadata. Here is My code :

```js
const find = require('find') ;
const mm = require('music-metadata') ;
const directories = ["C:\\Users\\{UserNamehere}\\Music\\"] // you can add more directories
async function parseMetadata(files){
   let metadata ;
   data = files.map(async (file) => {
      metadata = await mm.parseFile(file,{duration:true}) ;

      m = metadata.common ;
      return m ;
   }) ;

   const musicarray = await Promise.all(data) ;
   return musicarray ;
}


function fetchNewSongs(dirs){
   let res,musicfiles = [] ;
   
   dirs.forEach((path)=>{
      res = find.fileSync(/\.mp3/i,path) ;
      musicfiles.push(...res) ;
   });

   if (musicfiles.length !== 0){
      return parseMetadata(musicfiles) ;
   }
   else{
      return Promise.resolve([]) ;
   }
}


fetchNewSongs(directories).then( value => {
   console.log(value)
})
```

Problem arises when any music file is corrupted or it's metadata cannot be fetched by `music-metadata` causing the flow of parsing the metadata list to stop. I tried to rename a `.txt` to `.mp3` to reconstruct situation of a corrupted file. What I want is whenever parsing the metadata of a particular music file if an error occurs it just return empty array and then continue searching for other files. After the process is complete then removing those elements of array having empty objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a try/catch in your map function:

Mocked version:

```js
const mm = {
  parseFile(file) {
    return Promise.reject("Bad format");
  },
};

async function parseMetadata(files) {
  let metadata = files.map(async (file) => {
    try {
      metadata = await mm.parseFile(file, { duration: true });
    } catch (error) {
      return [];
    }

    m = metadata.common;
    return m;
  });

  return Promise.all(metadata);
}

async function fetchNewSongs(dirs = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]) {
  return parseMetadata(dirs);
}

fetchNewSongs().then(console.log, console.error);

// output : [ [], [], [] ]
```

As an addition you might go for a `for` loop and avoid having to filter your array afterward

```js
const mm = {
  parseFile(file) {
    return Promise.reject("Bad format");
  },
};

async function parseMetadata(files) {
  const metadataCollection = [];
  for (const file of files) {
    try {
      const metadata = await mm.parseFile(file, { duration: true });
      metadataCollection.push(metadata);
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error);
    }
  }
  return metadataCollection;
}

async function fetchNewSongs(dirs = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]) {
  return parseMetadata(dirs);
}

fetchNewSongs().then(console.log, console.error);

// outputs:
// Bad format
// Bad format
// Bad format
// []
```

Comment: Don't think you can use `let metadata = files.map(async (file) => {...`. Unless this is for illustrative purposes, `async/await` can't be used with the `map` function.

Comment: Why ? This will map to an array of promises later handled by the promise.all statement

Comment: Ah, I think I understand it now, you are resolving your promises at the end, with the `.then`. I usually just map the promises to an array without using async await and then  just return an `await Promise.all(array of promises)`. Different way to do it, sorry I did not spot it right away